# Development app greyed out and 'waiting' on iOs device/

Tags: ios, itunes

I've been using udk to develop my game, and I've just compiled and built a dev build. All my provisioning and certificates are fine, but when I install the app on my device via itunes, I run into issues.

The app installs normally, but once the process has completed, the app icon is greyed out, and occasionally says "waiting".

I've heard about this issue before for apps purchased over the app store, but none of the usual fixes seem to work. Resetting/resyncing does nothing.

Comment: if you have provisioning file, why aren't you just running through Xcode?

Comment: I'm developing with UDK which outputs the ipa file as a whole.